# Many categorys. How to design model if I want different form to each category?

Tags: django, database-design, models

I have many categorys:

- homes
- lands
- apartments

How to design model (optimally) if I want different form to each category? Each category has different fields (some repeats)

Comment: Different form, where? In the admin or in your application?

Comment: @JackShedd In the admin and in my app

Answer (score 3):

models.py

```
class model_abstract(models.Model):
     //repeat fields here

     class Meta:
         abstract = True             

class Home(model_abstract):

     //fields here

class Lands(model_abstract):

     //fields here

class Apartments(model_abstract):

     //fields here
```

forms.py

```
class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Home

class LandForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Lands

class ApartmentForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Apartments
```

Comment: Worth noting that this means that you can't (easily) do anything that should be common to all of the homes, lands, and apartments, which might be handy to do. In that case you want to do [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), though that brings in its own complications.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer and I upvoted it! I'm just pointing out that this approach has some downsides and linking to documentation about a similar approach with different advantages / disadvantages.

Comment: @Dougal sorry and thank you for telling me. And yeah all inheritance have advantages and disadvantages. I have read the book and this is only the inheritance that is the best in all 4 model inheritance

Comment: @Dougal It has only one disadvantages and that is, "it cannot use the parent class in isolation". Do you have better idea? This is only I can think of now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Really, these should be as catherine shows, separate models for each category, but:
2. That's probably not what you want, as you seem to have 1 table for all categories, with different fields showing depending on what the category is.
3. This is a really inelegant design, but I can sort of see it being handy if categories tie to other objects and you don't want to have to deal with the complication of tying multiple different models to another model in the same possible field (abstract relations are fun, but dirty).

**In Your Own Views**

Just write a different form for each category, and use the appropriate one where it's called for.

```
from forms HouseForm, LandForm, ApartmentForm

if category.name == 'homes':
    form = HouseForm()
elif category.name == 'lands':
    form = LandForm()
else:
    form = ApartmentForm()
```

**The Admin is trickier**

You'll need to define a modelform for each of the category types, overloading the modelform's fields attribute to only display the fields you care about. You can then override the ModelAdmin's form method to show a different form. Something *like* this:

```
class AdminHouseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['field_one']

class AdminLandForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['field_two']          

class AdminApartmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['field_two']

class CatgeoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = property(lambda cat: AdminLandForm if cat.name == 'lands' else AdminApartmentForm if cat.name == 'apartment' else AdminHouseForm)
```

I'm not 100% on that form override, but that should be a start.

You're gonna run into problems since, on creation, the TYPE of category isn't known until after save. There should be a way to work around that though.